# How to use django-tagit-label outside admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am currently working on a django project where one form is used outside the admin panel that requires tagging.

I found django-tagit-labels [Tagit Github](https://github.com/bennylope/django-taggit-labels) but it only works for admin panel forms, any idea on how to use it outside the admin panel in custom pages ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the django-taggit widget for your own tag model. Please check here http://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_tagging.html